# How to add BassFilter

Tags: javascript, audio

I have been trying to add a LowShelf filter to my code that changes the song based on the slider value. The value is changing, but there is no effect being added to the audio. Don't worry about me setting the value to 0, this is in my init function so that is the beginning value.
This is what the page looks like: https://people.rit.edu/sns9181/igme330/CookieClickerAudioVisualizer/Main.html

My Code:

```
//Audio Initialization
let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
let audio = document.querySelector('#song1');
analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);

//Bass Filter
bassFilter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
bassFilter.type = "lowshelf";
bassFilter.frequency.value = 0;

//Node Hookups
source.connect(bassFilter);
bassFilter.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a gain value.
Example: `bassFilter.gain.value = 0`